# How to enable SKAdNetwork for Google AdMob in my managed Expo React-Native app

Tags: react-native, expo, admob

So I have Google AdMob implemented in my Expo React-Native app and everything is working fine. I got this alert two days ago in AdMob console, I have been googling for the past two days but cannot find any answer to:

- How to enable enable SKAdNetwork to track conversions https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14?hl=en-US ?
- Do I need to do anything?

> Some apps haven't been configured to use Apple's SKAdNetwork
> To ensure you're getting credit for all ads activity, like app installs, be sure to configure SKAdNetwork with Google's recommended network IDs.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find out how to address this warning? I'm seeing the same and I'm unsure how to address it with react-native-google-mobile-ads

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [React Native Google Mobile Ads](https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads), and they have a [section](https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads#enable-skadnetwork-to-track-conversions-ios) in the docs for this.

Add the following to your `app.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  'react-native-google-mobile-ads': {
    android_app_id: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx',
    ios_app_id: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx',
    sk_ad_network_items: [
      "cstr6suwn9.skadnetwork",
      "4fzdc2evr5.skadnetwork",
      "4pfyvq9l8r.skadnetwork",
      "2fnua5tdw4.skadnetwork",
      "ydx93a7ass.skadnetwork",
      "5a6flpkh64.skadnetwork",
      "p78axxw29g.skadnetwork",
      "v72qych5uu.skadnetwork",
      "ludvb6z3bs.skadnetwork",
      "cp8zw746q7.skadnetwork",
      "3sh42y64q3.skadnetwork",
      "c6k4g5qg8m.skadnetwork",
      "s39g8k73mm.skadnetwork",
      "3qy4746246.skadnetwork",
      "f38h382jlk.skadnetwork",
      "hs6bdukanm.skadnetwork",
      "v4nxqhlyqp.skadnetwork",
      "wzmmz9fp6w.skadnetwork",
      "yclnxrl5pm.skadnetwork",
      "t38b2kh725.skadnetwork",
      "7ug5zh24hu.skadnetwork",
      "gta9lk7p23.skadnetwork",
      "vutu7akeur.skadnetwork",
      "y5ghdn5j9k.skadnetwork",
      "n6fk4nfna4.skadnetwork",
      "v9wttpbfk9.skadnetwork",
      "n38lu8286q.skadnetwork",
      "47vhws6wlr.skadnetwork",
      "kbd757ywx3.skadnetwork",
      "9t245vhmpl.skadnetwork",
      "eh6m2bh4zr.skadnetwork",
      "a2p9lx4jpn.skadnetwork",
      "22mmun2rn5.skadnetwork",
      "4468km3ulz.skadnetwork",
      "2u9pt9hc89.skadnetwork",
      "8s468mfl3y.skadnetwork",
      "klf5c3l5u5.skadnetwork",
      "ppxm28t8ap.skadnetwork",
      "ecpz2srf59.skadnetwork",
      "uw77j35x4d.skadnetwork",
      "pwa73g5rt2.skadnetwork",
      "mlmmfzh3r3.skadnetwork",
      "578prtvx9j.skadnetwork",
      "4dzt52r2t5.skadnetwork",
      "e5fvkxwrpn.skadnetwork",
      "8c4e2ghe7u.skadnetwork",
      "zq492l623r.skadnetwork",
      "3rd42ekr43.skadnetwork",
      "3qcr597p9d.skadnetwork"
    ],
  },
};
```